# How can I stop IK bones from spinning randomly?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, parent, inverse-kinematics

I'm  trying to rig Oleg Ushenok's Mech Spider. I'm using IK bones for the little pistons that are all over the model. I like the 3 part motion that it gives rather than the typical piston setup. The problem is when I parent the first bone in the chain, it causes the whole chain to spin on its Y axis.
The bones in question are activated by raising the gun (the blue curved bone). The movement I'm trying to add is rotating the turret with the gun (The yellow cross bone).
I'll include a link to the blend file, with only a small part of the model that's relevant.
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d0m9lh5qxy9pbzm/Spider%20Robot%20for%20Stack.blend?dl=0
[image]

Comment: Looking around the file, it doesn't appear that you have set a chain length for any of your IK constraints.  So when you parent them, suddenly everything else, going back to the root, gets involved in the IK.  This is not a situation where I would use IK, so I'm not sure exactly your goal here, but I'd be willing to wager that's at least part of the problem.

Comment: I have tried setting it, but it doesn't change the problem. I'm taking advantage of IK stretching to move the bit in the middle kinda independently of the rest of the piston. That's what I'm hoping to preserve. It works better on the 4 on top of the turret that turns with the lower green cross bone.